# Passing a razor object to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have my JS function:

```
function LoadJs(hostApp) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("LoadJs", "Home")',
        data: { "hostApp": hostApp },
        success: function (Js) {
            Response.Write(Js)   
        }
    });
}
```

When I call the function in my `Summary.vbhtml` file, I would like to pass it my hostApp object and then have the Javascript pass the object to a controller action.

Here is my `script` tag calling the `LoadJs` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    LoadJs( @(model)); 
</script>
```

I've tried `'@model'`, `'@(model)'`, and `@model`but nothing seems to pass it correctly. When I pass it the first two ways, it passes a string, which is not what I want and if I try the last way or the way in the example then it turned `@model` into the correct object, but it says it is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    LoadJs(@(Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model))));
</script>
```

Comment: My program is now giving a 500 error `No parameterless constructor defined for this object`. I have made my object class seriable and I have a parameterless constructor. Do you know why that would be happening?

Comment: And in the call stack of the exception, does it mark this line I posted or an other one?

Comment: It is being called on the @Url.Action in my js function

Comment: I know this isn't related to the question, and you're answer is working it seems. If you can answer if that would be a huge help though.

Comment: What if you put there `'@Html.ActionLink("LoadJs", "Home")'`, does it work? EDIT: No, it won't work.

Comment: Do you have the `LoadJs` function in the vbhtml file directly or in a separate `js` file?

Comment: It says that it is not a member of `System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper`